# Affect on C_ds in MOSFET turn off

Tags: mosfet

Question boils down to whether the voltage across a capacitor can ever exceed Q/C.  It relates to what happens to the drain-source capacitance when a NFET turns off.  At the start of turn off V_ds and charge of C_ds is essentially zero.  In my case drain current is a low 1.5mA.  When gate voltage is removed and drops to V_gp (at the Miller plateau) I_d remains constant at 1.5mA and V_ds starts to rise and reaches it maximum (V_dd) when the gate-drain capacitance is discharged in a few nsec (at the end of the Miller plateau.)  Then I_d starts to fall to zero.  My problem is, unless V of a capacitor can ever exceed Q/C, which I think it cannot, V_ds cannot rise any faster than the drain-source capacitance can be charged.  If the drain-source capacitance takes all of the drain current, I_d, (does it or is the current divided between the capacitance and the drain-source FET path??) I calculate it would take about 350nsec for V_ds to reach 90%.  Calculation is not straight forward:  in my case I have a 5.6K resistor feeding C_ds, but that changes from 50pf at V_ds = 0 to 26pf at V_ds = 10.  The datasheet says turn off is 8nsec.  I calculate 350nsec.  Am I doing this correctly?

There are encyclopedias on the gate-drain and the gate-source parasitic capacitances, but nothing that I could find on the drain-source capacitance.  I suspect because all example use 1A to 20A as the drain current which will charge the D-S capacitance in a flash.

Comment: Have you see this app note  https://www.vishay.com/docs/73217/an608a.pdf

Comment: Yes.  It is an excellent App Note, but it didn't address my question -- though it got close.

Comment: What was the test circuit used in the datasheet to determine the turn off time?

Comment: These test circuits never use any affecting external components.

Comment: This is why you cannot expect 8nsec with RL = 5.6k plus some additional parasitic capacitance.

Comment: Are you comfortable with Miller Effect?

Comment: Yes familiar and close to comfortable, but I don't think the Miller effect is involved with the drain-source capacitance.  My understanding is that initial gate voltage charges the gate-source capacitance with an increasing gate voltage.  Then it reaches the Miller plateau and starts charging the gate-drain capacitance with no change in the gate voltage.  Then after the Miller plateau it charges both (I think??) as the gate voltage rises to its maximum.  What I don't know is that the gate-drain capacitance (but not the gate-source capacitance) is also part of the output capacitance, C_oss.